# All digits of $2^n$ are even if and only if $n=1,2,3,6,11$

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

All digits of $2^n$ are even if and only if $n=1,2,3,6,11$.

For example, 
$2^1=2,2^2=4,2^3=8,2^4=16,2^5=32,2^6=64,\ldots,2^{11}=2048,2^{12}=4096$.

Do you know a proof of this fact or some related results ?
Or do you have a counter example ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116026/is-2048-the-highest-power-of-2-with-all-even-digits-base-ten.

Comment: Based on the comment of the OP in the linked question about finite sequences appearing in large enough powers of 2, maybe a (quite hard too) way to tackle the problem would be to prove that the number $0.1248163264...$ obtained writing the successive powers of 2 is universal (if such a terminology exists, in French we say "nombre univers").

Comment: Ok, wikipedia just taught me it is called a "disjunctive sequence" in English.

Comment: If all the digits of $2^n$ are even, then all of the digits of $2^{n-1}$ are no more than $4$...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of a question on math.stackexchange.com